# Order a data frame in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

If I have a list of data frames

```
list.dfs <- list(df1 = data.frame(var1 = c(1:3), var2 = c(1:3), var3 = c(1:3)), 
      df2 = data.frame(var1= c(1:3), var2 = c(1:3), var3 = c(1:3)), 
      df3 = data.frame(var1= c(1:3), var2 = c(1:3), var3 = c(3:1)))
```

How do I use `lapply` and order to sort every data frame in the list by `var3` (lowest to highest)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried?  This is fairly straight forward and as it stands it sounds like you're asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very good a R yet, sorry for the straight forward question. I am having trouble extracting the columns of the data frame within a list to pass to the order function

Comment: I have tried lapply(list.dfs,order([3],). Sorry df's in lists confuse me. I know how to order them normally not using lapply. For example list.dfs[[3]][order(list.dfs[[3]][3]),]

Comment: Sven's answer is correct.  The thing to think about is writing a function that does what you want on a single data frame, e.g. `function(x) x[order(x$var3),]`.  Then use `lapply` to apply that function to your list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lapply(list.dfs, function(x) x[order(x$var3), ])
```

will do the trick.